# Flutter Sliver App Bar not working with Custom Scroll View and controller

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have a Sliver Floating App Bar I have been using for my app, which sits in a Nested Scroll View, and the body of that Nested Scroll View is a Custom Scroll View. I just added a controller to the custom scroll view  so that I can have a "go back to top" button, but upon adding this controller the floating app bar no longer floats. When I remove the controller it works again. Anybody know if there is a way to give a Custom scroll view a controller and still maintain the functionality of the sliver appbar?

Comment: can you include [minimal-snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, answered my question as soon as I posted it (murphy's law)

You just need to pass the controller to the nested scroll view instead of the custom scroll view.